# How to create Contact record using existing Account record id I have tried but the code is not working properly?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to create contact record using existing account Id in Aura lightning table ?
and I want save a row separately in on submit button it perform bulk insert ?
[image]

Component Code:-

```
    <aura:component controller="AddDelRowDynamic" 
  implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
   flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
  force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableFo 
   rAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

  <!--Aura Attribute Start-->
  <aura:attribute name="contactList" type="Contact[]"/>
  <aura:attribute name="showTableFlag" type="boolean" 
 default="false"></aura:attribute>
 <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"/>
 <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
 <!--Aura Attribute End-->
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/> 

<lightning:card>
    <div class="slds-m-around--xx-large">
        <h1 class="slds-page-header__title">Add Row 
            <lightning:buttonIcon 
                                  iconName="utility:add"  
                                  size="large" 
                                  variant="bare" 
                                  alternativeText="Add" 
                                  onclick="{!c.addRowController}"/>
        </h1>
        
        <!--Table Start-->
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showTableFlag}">
            <div class="container-fluid"> 
                <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer"> 
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate">Sr. No</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="First Name">First Name</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Last Name">Last Name</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Action">Action</div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>   
                    <tbody>      
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="objCon" indexVar="index">
                            <tr>
                                <td> 
                                    {!index + 1}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <lightning:input name="FirstName" type="text" maxlength="50" value="{!objCon.FirstName}" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <lightning:input name="LastName" required="true" type="text" maxlength="50" value="{!objCon.LastName}" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <lightning:input name="Account Name"  label="Account Name" value="{!v.account.Name}" disabled="true"/>
                                    
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick="{!c.deleteRecordController}" data-record="{!index}">
                                        <lightning:icon 
                                                        iconName="utility:delete" 
                                                        size="small" 
                                                        alternativeText="Delete"/>
                                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete</span>
                                    </a>
                                </td> 
                            </tr>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-top_small">
                    <lightning:button 
                                      variant="brand" 
                                      label="Submit" 
                                      title="Brand action" 
                                      onclick="{!c.saveContactsController}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </aura:if>
        <!--Table End-->
        
    </div>
 </lightning:card>
 </aura:component>
```

Controller Code:-

```
({
addRowController : function(component, event, helper) {
    //get the contact List from component  
    var contactList = component.get("v.contactList");
    //Add New Contact Record
    contactList.push({
        'sobjectType': 'Contact',
        'Name': '',
        'Phone': '',
        'Fax': '',
        'Website ': '', 
        
    });
    component.set("v.contactList", contactList);
    component.set("v.showTableFlag", true);
},

deleteRecordController : function(component, event, helper) {
    //Get the contact list
    var contactList = component.get("v.contactList");
    //Get the target object
    var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
    //Get the selected item index
    var index = selectedItem.dataset.record;
    //Remove single record from contact list
    contactList.splice(index, 1);
    //Set modified contact list
    component.set("v.contactList", contactList);
},
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
    
    var accid = component.get("v.recordId");
    component.set("v.contact.AccountId",component.get("v.recordId"));
    var action = component.get('c.getAccount');
    action.setParams({
        acid : component.get("v.recordId")            
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
            console.log('Received Data'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            component.set("v.account",response.getReturnValue());
        }else{
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    
},
saveContactsController : function(component, event, helper) {      
    if (helper.validateContactRecords(component, event)) {
        //Call Apex method and pass contact list as a parameters
        var action = component.get("c.insertCon");
        action.setParams({"newcon": component.get("v.contactList")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            //get response status 
            var state = response.getState();
            alert(state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert('y')
                var contactid=response.getReturnValue().Id;
                alert("contact created.Id:"+contactid)
                var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                navEvt.setParams({
                    "recordId": contactid,
                    "slideDevName": "related"
                });
                navEvt.fire();
                component.set("v.contactList", []);
                alert('Contacts saved successfully');
                component.set("v.showTableFlag", true);
            }
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
     }
   })
```

Helper Code:-

```
  ({
     validateContactRecords: function(component, event) {
    //Validate all contact records
    var isValid = true;
    var contactList = component.get("v.contactList");
    for (var i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++) {
        if (contactList[i].LastName == '') {
            isValid = false;
            alert('Contact LastName cannot be blank on '+(i + 1)+' 
          row number');
         }
      }
      return isValid;
     },
  })
```

Apec Class:-

```
  public class AddDelRowDynamic {

@AuraEnabled
public static void saveAccountList(List<Account> accList){
    insert accList;    
}
@AuraEnabled
public static contact insertCon(Contact newcon)
{
    insert newcon;
    return newcon;        
}
@AuraEnabled
public static Account getAccount(string acid)
{
    Account acc = [select id,name from Account where Id =:acid];
    return acc;
   }
  }
```

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky Please help me !

Comment: Sorry, is it still actual?